# Esp8266 fatal timeout error

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I recently got my esp8266-01 and for interfacing with Arduino I completed all the steps need for right form pins to board allotting from esp8266 community after everything I still get error of "connection failed fatal error : timeout ", so anyone just help out for
 soln ? 
I am interfacing with empty code of loops only to check it's response at connectivity at first .

Comment: how did you wire it? is it the esp-01S version? did you put it in flashing mode for upload?

Comment: Rx to Rx and tx to tx , vcc 3.3, channel 5 , esp8266 - 01, no I had put it for blink mode for basic checking of module